# Handling Exceptions in MVC JSON Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for the best approach at handling errors in a controller when returning a JSON result.

Firstly, what would be the best practice if I get an unhandled exception in my controller and I'm returning JSON? I'm thinking 400 or 500 error? Client checks the status and does whatever.

I'm playing with a FilterAttribute and an IExceptionFilter but I can't get the OnException function to call. I've got the attribute applied to a controller action.

Any ideas why that might not be calling?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class AjaxHandleErrorAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    // This is never called !!!
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (filterContext.Exception != null 
            && !filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            ...
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = "Error processing                 request";
            ...
        }
    }
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController(IMyRepository repo)
    {
        ...
    }

    [AjaxHandleError]
    public ActionResult GetSomeJson(int anId)
    {
        throw new System.Exception();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should decorate your controller with that attribute or in your global.asax.cs you need to add

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
    filters.Add(new AjaxHandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

and your OnException method will be called.